# Use if statement update table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use this command to update `saving.balance` using IF statement:

```
UPDATE TABLE saving s, time t
SET s.balance = IF(t.currency_TYPE = ‘RMB’, s.balance + t.balance * t.interest)
WHERE t.ID = 'input'
AND s.User = t.User;
```

However, MySQL gives me `ERROR 1064`, what's wrong and how to correct it?

Comment: There is no `else` in your `if`

Comment: You probably need the else part of the if condition. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916827/mysql-if-statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot the 3th argument in your the IF function  and other syntax stuff :-)

why you make you script not with where? like this:

```
UPDATE saving s
INNER JOIN time t
    ON t.ID = 'input'
    AND t.User = s.User
SET s.balance = s.balance + t.balance * t.interest
WHERE t.currency_TYPE = 'RMB';
```

you will update just records with currency_type rmb!

OR

```
UPDATE saving s
INNER JOIN time t
    ON t.ID = 'input'
    AND t.User = s.User
SET s.balance = (t.currency_TYPE = 'RMB', s.balance + t.balance * t.interest, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
UPDATE saving s
INNER JOIN `time` t ON s.`User` = t.`User`
SET s.balance = CASE 
                  WHEN t.currency_TYPE = 'RMB' THEN s.balance + 
                                                    t.balance * t.interest
                  ELSE s.balance -- Don't forgot this, default is NULL
                END
WHERE t.ID = 'input';
```

**Or:**

```
UPDATE saving s
INNER JOIN `time` t ON s.`User` = t.`User`
SET s.balance = s.balance + t.balance * t.interest
WHERE t.ID = 'input'
  AND t.currency_TYPE = 'RMB' ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to mention the else part

```
UPDATE TABLE saving s, time t
SET s.balance = IF(t.currency_TYPE = ‘RMB’, s.balance + t.balance * t.interest , 0)
WHERE t.ID = 'input'
AND s.User = t.User;
```